# sharepoint is telling us to convert doc to docx and not retaining version history

Tags: document-library, document, file

Sharepoint is telling us to convert Doc to Docx and not giving us a option not convert and keep as we are. If we convert, it looses version history which is important to us for auditing purposes. We are closing the company this year so we don't need to future proof our selves with the new docx format. Does anyone know how to turn off the conversion process or covert and keep the document history?